# use rested on or depended on? in "His decision to sail ____ his belief that the world was round."

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

Which phrase is properer, rested on or depended on?

> His decision to sail ____ his belief that the world was round.

I think both of them would work, but my teacher said "rested on" is better? Could anyone point out the nuances between the two?

Having searched on M-W dic, the definition of [rest on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rest%20on%2Fupon) is "to depend or rely on (someone or something)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two phrases are extremely similar. If this was a graded exam question, marking one as "correct" and the other as "incorrect" would not feel right to me.

But you might say that `rested on` implies a *little* bit more humanity or emotion, where `depended on` has a *little* bit more dispassionate or analytic implication. A **belief** might "rest on" an opinion while a **mathematical proof** might "depend on" a certain axiom. This is really splitting hairs though.